# constructors in abstract methods and extends methods

Tags: java, constructor

Few basics questions about constructors in different classes in JAVA:

1. When should I add an empty constructor in a class?
2. When should I add constructor in abstract class?
3. When should I add a "super" constructor in an extends class?

Comment: This question is off topic here because it is too broad. This question is asking for a chapter in an Java textbook (like [this one for example](http://www.mindview.net/Books/TIJ/)) not an answer to a specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

1. Empty constructor is generated automatically, but only if class doesn't have constructor with parameters. So, if you have a constructor with parameters, and you want to have empty constructor, you must write one yourself.
2. Most common case if you have some private/protected fields in abstract class.
   For example, if abstract class Person has fields name, surname, it should have constructor that initializes these 2 fields. If class Student extends class Person, it should call Person constructor.
3. parent class default constructor(without parameters) is called automatically. Use super if you want to call parent constructor with parameters.

Answer (score 0):

1. Empty constructor exists implicitly. However if you added other constructors and still need default constructor, add it explicitly. Other reason is if you want to control the constructor access modifier. The implicit default constructor is public.
2. Constructors create objects. If you want to create ready-to use object that holds some state you typically have to code constructor. In this case it does not matter whether the class is abstract or not.
3. I believe that you mean when you have to explicitly invoke super class' constructor from subclass. You have to do this unless you want to invoke not default constructor of super class. I'd recommend to always call constructor of super class explicitly. Such code is safer for future modifications.

Comment: `The implicit default constructor is public` only if class is public. In other words visibility modifier of default constructor is same as visibility of class.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you need explicit default constructor, and implicit default constructor is not available.
2. There're subclasses of that class.
3. Calling non-default constructor of the superclass.